# How to solve this differential equation? It's not separable, nor exact nor homogeneous.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is:

$$(1+x+y)dy - (1-3x-3y)dx= 0$$

How can I solve the question?

Solution:

$$3x + y + 2ln(-x - y +1) = k$$

I've tried by the integrating factor method, substitution...

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the substitution  $z=y+x$. Then $y=z-x$, $dy/dx=dz/dx-1$. 
The equation becomes

$\frac{dz}{dx}-1=\frac{1-3z}{1+z}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $y'=\frac{-3x-3y+1}{x+y+1}$ is of the form $y'=f\left(\frac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}\right)$. If $a_1b_2-a_2b_1\neq0$ then there is one way of solving it. In this case it does equal zero, so here is how it goes:

There is $\lambda\neq0$ so that $a_1=\lambda a_2$ and $b_1=\lambda b_2$. In this case $\lambda=-3$. Substitution: $u=a_2x+b_2y$ and you get $u'=1+\frac{-3u+1}{u+1}$.

Comment: does this method have a name?

Comment: Well, English is not my first language, so I don't know :) It's a generalization of a homogeneous equation and the method is substitution.

Comment: at least now I have some terms to search, I am learning diffQ (Using English Slang) and the vocabulary is killing me, because the book just says use <Vocab> which one is just to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it :). I didn't remember this generalization of homogeneous equations

Comment: You're welcome :) If you found it helpful, you can accept it as 'best answer'.

Answer (score 0):

Using kmitov's approach, you can continue and write  $\frac{dz}{dx}=2\frac {1-z}{1+z}$ and now write the reverse, expressing  $\frac{dx}{dz}$ and it becomes a very simple differential equation.